# Exporting AD group memberships of users in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to export a list of all groups a user is assigned to. This command works fine for my needs:

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership username | select name | Export-Csv filepath
```

However I have to review about 100 users in my company, so I would like to to merge those CSVs in an Excel spreadsheet. My problem is that when I merge the CSVs, I just have a random list of AD groups.

A solution for this problem would be to export a CSV with two columns while column 1 consists of the AD username and column 2 of the AD groupname, eg.

> User A | Group A; User A | Group B; User A | Group C

I already have figured out that this probably won't be possible with `Get -ADPrincipalGroupMembership` but unfortunately I haven't found any solution yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format you're considering is terrible for both viewing and processing. Either build a list mapping the user to each group (one mapping per line)

```
$users = 'userA', 'userB', ...
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user |
              Select-Object -Expand Name
    $groups | ForEach-Object {
        New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
            'User'  = $user
            'Group' = $_
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv 'output.csv' -NoType
```

or join the list of groups with a secondary delimiter and map a user to all of its groups like that:

```
$users = 'userA', 'userB', ...
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user |
              Select-Object -Expand Name
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        'User'  = $user
        'Group' = $groups -join '|'
    }
} | Export-Csv 'output.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Im not a power powershell user at all, so I really appreciate the help.